# how to NOT get mobile version of a website in java?

Tags: java, extract, html

This code returns the mobile version of a website. How to get a desktop version instead?

```
InputStreamReader page = new InputStreamReader(new URL('http://www.***.com/').openStream());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a user agent that matchs a Desktop browser

Edited with sources

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.clarku.edu/");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:16.0.1) Gecko/20121011 Firefox/16.0.1");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: If you add the User-Agent that uses a desktop browser it will returns the desktop website version, i updated the answer with sources.

Comment: So if this answer correct, please, mark it and other users can have a way to follow. Thanks!